# How to erase button separator in btn-group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need to delete this lines, which is outlined on image.

This is a button separator, and I dont need them now, how to delete it?

Image is here:
http://i61.tinypic.com/25klh7s.png

Class structure is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn transition" id="about">
            About me
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn transition" id="job">
            My job
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn transition" id="contact">
            Contact
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle of some live link instead of a static image?

Comment: try applying `border:none;` to buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: browser.
In Chrome I have this problem, in IE don't. 
But I fix it by adding some style rules. 
Here is code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn transition" style="margin-right: 1px" id="about">
        About me
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn transition" id="job">
        My job
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn transition" style="margin-right: 0px" id="contact">
        Contact
    </button>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at your css rules, because there are not default bootstrap lines around the buttons: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZe6r/).

By the way, if you look at default bootstrap `.btn` style definition, you can see only transparent border:

```
.btn {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Inspection styles with developer tools in your browser could help you with problem determining.